# ggplot2 geom_point with pattern fill

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a chart that is measuring a risk variable through time for a number of people - I've added a snippet of the plot below:

[image]

The colours here represent risk - I would like add an additional variable to the plot and represent this by changing the pattern on individual points. In excel, it is possible to fill points with patterns such as stripes, hashed etc. Is this possible within the geom_point aesthetic in ggplot2?

I realise varying the shape of the points would accomplish the same thing but this is not as visually immediate as varying the pattern.

Comment: I think you could just add type={variable} to the aesthetic.

Comment: @JarnSchöber I changed the geom_point code to the following: geom_point(aes(colour = df$colour, size = 3, type = df$shape)). Unfortunately that returns:  Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: type

Comment: Actually it is `shape={variable}`

Comment: @thothal Thats it!

Comment: @thothal thanks, the shape option does work - by suggesting this are you implying it is not possible to vary the pattern fill of a point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Use the shape option.

Yes, it is possible to change the shape of points according to a variable you have.

You have to use the option `shape` when mapping. This is a quick example with `mtcars` dataframe:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg, shape=as.factor(cyl))) +
  geom_point()
```

> **Note**: Just remember that a continuous variable can not be mapped to shape.

Hope this helps.

Comment: By suggesting the use of shapes, are you implying it is not possible to vary the pattern of the point?

Comment: Maybe with some external library is possible, but in general, you can fill only with color and if you want to change the pattern you can use `shape`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Besides changing the shape you can use filled dots, where you can change `color` and `fill` separately. For this you need a symbol (`shape`) in the range between `21` and  `25`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg, fill = as.factor(am), color = as.factor(vs))) + 
   geom_point(shape = 21, size = 4) + 
   scale_fill_manual(values = c("white", "lightgray")) + 
   scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "orange"))
```

[image: Filled Dots]